# Click Item Inside Text box HTML not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to implement `click` event on the items inside the text box. But it doesn't work. Here is the code. Please help!

```
<div class="right-inner-addon" id="address_box" >
    <i class="icon-search"  onclick="alert('add')"></i>
    <a class="icon-search" onclick="alert('lsearch')"></a>
    <input type="search" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

[image: this is what it looks like]

Comment: I don't know why it fails ?? Any idea?? Plz help Cheers ...

Comment: Your input element is not in the <a> tags. I'm not sure if that is purposeful or not but it definitely is your problem if you are expecting lsearch to be alerted to the user when you click in the textbox.

Comment: Something like this: `<a class="icon-search" onclick="alert('lsearch')"><input type="search" class="form-control" /></a>`

Comment: what abot the other button ?? there are rwo buttons

Comment: do both of them not work?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="right-inner-addon" id="address_box" >
    <i class="icon-search"></i>
    <input type="search" onclick="alert('lsearch')" class="form-control"   />
```

Comment: it is not for the text box

Comment: Post your CSS in your question. It may be that you're using `after:` for your `icon-search` class and therefore does not have any area to click.

Answer (score 0):

Post more your css, please.
And you can open google dev tools and use the function for trace events  " Event Listener Breakpoints" in Sources, Click in " Mouse" and choose " Click" .
Now you can click in your input and see target element in dev tools.

Comment: Any straight forward solution for this plzzz